# Доступ к выбранному селектору

Tags: html, jquery

Всем привет. Есть такой скрипт

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var itemBox = '.check-div';       // контейнер записи, id записи храним в data-id
    $(".checkbox_visible").change(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $thisItem = $this.closest(itemBox);
        var thisIndex = $thisItem.attr('data-id');
        if ($this.prop("checked")){
            var c=1;
        } else {
            var c=0;
        }
            $.ajax({
              url:'/ajax/update_visible_transport',
              data:{'itemid':thisIndex,
               'c':c},
              success:function(r){
                    if (c==1) {
                        $('.active-transport').slideDown(500);
                        $('.deactive-transport').slideUp(500);
                    }
                    if (c==0) {
                        $('.active-transport').slideUp(500);
                        $('.deactive-transport').slideDown(500);
                    }
              }
        });
        });
}); 
</script>
```

И такой HTML

```
<div class="col-12 col-md check-div" data-id="<?echo $transportItem['id'];?>">
                        <div class="f-block">
                            <div>
                                <p class="active-transport">Объявление активно</p>
                                <p class="deactive-transport">Объявление неактивно</p>
                                <br />
                                <label class="switch" >
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="visible" value="1" class="checkbox_visible" <?if ($transportItem['visible']==1) {?>
                                                  checked=""<?;}?>/>
                                  <span class="slider"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            
                          
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

При нажатии на чекбокс, убирается и добавлятся надпись

```
<p class="active-transport">Объявление активно</p>
<p class="deactive-transport">Объявление неактивно</p>
```

работает все нормально. Но проблема в том, что у меня могут быть несколько блоков таких объявлений, соответсвенно, класс повторяется. Как получить доступ по селектору именно нужного блока p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $thisItem.find('.active-transport').slideDown(500);
```